# If air can be dissolved in water, is water vapour dissolved in air?

Tags: solubility

If O2 dissolved in water acts like a liquid even though it is a high temperature, then is water vapour in the air "dissolved" as it acts like a gas at less than 100C? Or is there a different word for it (suspension)?

Comment: Mixtures of gases are never called solutions.

Comment: Water vapour is just part of the air. You can call air "gaseous solution" if you want, IUPAC won't sue you. Heck, air is even a suspension if there are liquid droplets, or dust particles.

Comment: While gas mixtures may be formally called solutions as homogenous mixtures, there is important different to conventional solutions. Water vapor as gaseous form of water is not being dissolved by air. Vapor would be there even if there would be no air.